# Scan for groups of consecutive words

Tags: ruby

Given the input:

```
str = "foo bar jim jam. jar jee joon."
```

I need the output of all 2- and 3-word phrases that are separated by spaces:

```
[ "foo bar", "bar jim", "jim jam", "jar jee", "jee joon",
  "foo bar jim", "bar jim jam", "jar jee joon" ]
```

Note in particular the lack of "jam jar", "jim jam jar" and "jam jar jee" in the above, due to the period.

I can't use `str.scan(/\w+/).each_cons(2).map{ |a| a.join(' ') }` because that would include `"jam jar"`.

Scanning for `/\w+ \w+/` yields `["foo bar", "jim jam", "jar jee"]`, notably missing "bar jim" and "jee joon", and highlighting the problem.

*The real-world application for this is generating a phrase-based index for a search engine. I want to find all the truly-consecutive words as phrases, excluding those with punctuation separating words.*

**Edit**: Seems like there might be a way to do this in regex/scan via a variation on:

```
"a b c d".scan(/(?=([abc] [abc]) )[abc]/)
#=> [["a b"], ["b c"]]
```

Comment: Why not split `str` into sentences and scan them individually?

Comment: @mu Because I didn't think of that previously. I'll take that track now.

Comment: I suppose you got stuck in the "all I have is a hammer" trap :)

Comment: That trap is the only trap I know! :)

Comment: I haven't done enough to earn anything so feel free to answer yourself or see if someone else has a New and Improved TurboHammer Mark-II.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does the job, although it assumes the only punctuation is in the form of periods:

```
str.split(".").map do |s|
  pairs_and_triples = []
  s.split.each_cons(2){ |*words| pairs_and_triples << words.join(" ") }
  s.split.each_cons(3){ |*words| pairs_and_triples << words.join(" ")}
  pairs_and_triples
end.flatten
```

**EDIT** or with a little less repitition:

```
str.split(".").map do |s|
  [2,3].map do |i|
    s.split.each_cons(i).map{ |*words| words.join(" ") }
  end.flatten
end.flatten
```

Comment: Note that as of Ruby 1.9.2+ you can use `a = b.flat_map{…}` instead of `a = b.map{…}.flatten`. I've given you the acceptance since at the core it matches what I ended up doing. (See my answer capturing the code using a regex to define sentence boundaries and splitting the words only once each sentence.)

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "foo bar jim jam. jar jee joon."
arr = str.split(' ').each_cons(2).map do |a|
  a.join(' ') if a.join(' ').match(/\w+ \w+/)
end
p arr.compact
#=> ["foo bar", "bar jim", "jim jam.", "jar jee", "jee joon."]
```

EDIT: It appears you've changed your question to ask for 3-word phrases as well. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I did not change that aspect, but any solution that works for one should be able to work for 2-n (independently) and may be concatenated later.

Comment: Well, this does indeed work if you're just looking for 2-word phrases, and you should be able to replace `each_cons(2)` with `each_cons(x)` and change the regex to X words.

Answer (score 0):

The robust, efficient solution I ended up with was the one suggested by @muistooshort and sketched out by @ChrisRice:

1. split on sentence boundaries
2. scan for words (ignoring uninteresting punctuation like commas)
3. use `each_cons` to process the variations on that array

In code:

```ruby
max_words_per_phrase = 5
str = "foo bar, jim jam. jar: jee joon."

phrases = str.split(/[.!?]+/).flat_map do |sentence|
  words = sentence.scan(/\w+/)
  2.upto(max_words_per_phrase).flat_map do |i|
    words.each_cons(i).map{ |a| a.join(' ') }
  end
end

p phrases
#=> ["foo bar", "bar jim", "jim jam", "foo bar jim", "bar jim jam",
#=>  "foo bar jim jam", "jar jee", "jee joon", "jar jee joon"]
```

Answer (score 0):

After removing punctuation:

```
str = "foo bar jim jam jar jee joon"
```

As you suggested in your question, a positive lookahead could be used:

```
r2 = /(\w+)(?=(\s+\w+))/
r3 = /(\w+)(?=(\s+\w+)(\s+\w+))/
str.scan(r2).concat(str.scan(r3)).map(&:join)
  #=> ["foo bar", "bar jim", "jim jam", "jam jar", "jar jee", "jee joon",
  #    "foo bar jim", "bar jim jam", "jim jam jar", "jam jar jee", "jar jee joon"]
```